# Where to put component did mount in my next.js file

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, next.js

Halo guys, sorry for this stupid question but where do I put componentDidMount() in my react js document?

I am trying to insert google analytics script and I found a video on it but I dont know where to put that element. I will give you a screenshot of my file.

Thank you
(I know my editor is weird, but visual studio code keeps on crashing)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to create a Layout Component

Example:

```
// components/layout.js
import React from 'react'
import { initGA, logPageView } from '../utils/analytics'

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    if (!window.GA_INITIALIZED) {
      initGA()
      window.GA_INITIALIZED = true
    }
    logPageView()
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can then use Layout to wrap other components

Example:

```
// pages/about.js
import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default () => (
  <Layout>
    <div>About us</div>
  </Layout>
)
```

Example:

```
// utils/analytics.js
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

export const initGA = () => {
  console.log('GA init')
  ReactGA.initialize('UA-xxxxxxxxx-1')
}
export const logPageView = () => {
  console.log(`Logging pageview for ${window.location.pathname}`)
  ReactGA.set({ page: window.location.pathname })
  ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname)
}
export const logEvent = (category = '', action = '') => {
  if (category && action) {
    ReactGA.event({ category, action })
  }
}
export const logException = (description = '', fatal = false) => {
  if (description) {
    ReactGA.exception({ description, fatal })
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Im getting an error saying it can't resolve ".. utils/analytics" but i have installed react-ga?

Comment: `../utils/analytics` it's just an example showing that you might have some GA logic in there.

Comment: I've added an example for `../utils/analytics` file

Comment: So i dont know how my utils folder got lost, anyways i added one and inserted your code it still cant find the module

Comment: That's probably something with you folders structure.

Comment: You could also move all `utils/analytics` code into `About` as you did in the screenshot you've attached if you prefer. Mine it's just an example for you to understand.

Comment: I will upload my folder structure now

Comment: Im receiving no errors but also no data is loaded onto google analytics and no conolse.log text is displayed

Answer (score 9):

hey it seems like you find the answer but here is my take on it, maybe it will help someone else.

componentDidMount can only work in class component. from the image it's shown that About is functional component.

in this cases, React.useEffect is the equivalent of componentDidMount in functionl components. It can be used to invoke the init (or do any other side effects)

```
 const About = () => {
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
    
     ReactGA.init()
    
    }, [])
    
    //rest of the component
return ( 

<section> .... </section>

)

    
}
```

A little note you might want to consider, is using the _app.js component.

this is the next js base component and it wraps all of the pages, so any logic or layout used in all pages can be inserted there.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.init()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

this will run only on the component mount, and the benefit is that the app won't load it anymore on any other component mount and the api will be accessible through out the app.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.